# Python syntax for php (except KeyError)

Tags: python

I use a `python` module and rewrite it for `php`. I can't understand the meaning of `except KeyError`. How can implement it in php?

**Python:** (The location of last else is a bit strange)

```
for p1 in primefactors(n):
    try:
        factors[p1] += 1
    except KeyError:
        # when this block runs?
        factors[p1] = 1
```

I searched, but couldn't found out. Any idea?

Comment: Where's your PHP code? Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: `I searched, but couldn't found out.` I'm sorry but I really doubt that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError

Comment: @KhorneHoly I don't even  understand about `KeyError`. Sorry, I'm very new in python.

Comment: @DeepSpace I found that, but couldn't understand the meaning :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `KeyError` exception is raised when trying to naively (ie not using a dictionary's `get` method) accessing a non existing key in a dictionary:

```
dic = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(dic['c'])
# KeyError: 'c'
```

In order to catch this exception use `try-except` that catches `KeyError`:

```
dic = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
try:
    print(dic['c'])
except KeyError:
    print("'c' is not in the dictionary")
# 'c' is not in the dictionary
```